# i.MX7Dual - changing brightness via ScreenManager in DP6

Tags: android-things

Hi. In DP6 Google adds new API to modify screen - [ScreenManager](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/device/ScreenManager.html). I tried to use it to change brightness in i.MX7Dual, which is board from official Google kit [Pico Pro](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d-kit.html), but without success.

I created simple Activity with buttons, one for low brightness, one for high brightness:

```
Button lowButton = findViewById(R.id.button_low);

lowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
            Display[] displays = displayManager.getDisplays();
            if (displays.length > 0) {
                int id = displays[0].getDisplayId();
                ScreenManager screenManager = new ScreenManager(id);
                screenManager.setBrightnessMode(ScreenManager.BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
                screenManager.setBrightness(10);
            }
        }
    });
```

With permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.MODIFY_SCREEN_SETTINGS" />
```

It doesn't work, screen all the time bright same light, I suppose max.
Also I tried run dummy Activity to refresh screen but now improve.

I also tried changing brightness via Setting.System:

```
try {
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 10);

    int br = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = (float) br / 10;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

With permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

But it also doesn't work.

Any advice what check or try? I suppose this screen doesn't support changing screen brightness, because in new IoT Launcher I don't see screen settings.

[Sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSxZD.jpg)

Comment: Using the `Settings.System` API is definitely not going to work. The original snippet should work. It may be useful to [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192720%2B).

Comment: This issue should have been corrected in the DP6.1 release. If you are still having problems, please update your question.

Comment: As of today Feb 01 '18 with 0.6.1 devpreview on Pico Pro i.MX7, I cannot get it work either.